# Can I get the derived data path from xcodetools?

Tags: xcode, macos, command-line

I have scripts that do things with files in the derived data directories of some projects. By default, they live at:

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-gcfeadjvfsnyrwbxinmywoozajcf
```

I don't want to hardcode it, and I don't want to set it explicity. Can I get Xcode to tell me what it would use by default? The output of `xcodebuild -dry-run` and `xcodebuild -list` didn't help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following command will list all your build settings:

```
xcodebuild -dry-run -showBuildSettings
```

which should show the current derived data directory default.

Comment: Nailed it, except -dry-run isn't needed.

Comment: Saved my life. TNX ;)

Comment: @MattWilding: `-dry-run` seems to skip the resolving and downloading of packages.